Is there an accepted set of assumptions underlying logistic regression?
Searching the internet for 'logistic regression assumption' turns up 3, 4, 5 or 6 assumptions. Of six textbooks on logistic/generalized regression I looked at, only one clearly states the assumptions: Beyond Multiple Linear Regression by Roback & Legler, quoted below. No sources I can find, including the textbook, provide citations for the assumptions.
It seems that some authors add sensitivity to outliers, non-multicollinearity and/or sample size as assumptions of the model, which doesn't seem right -- these can cause problems, but (I think) aren't used in the derivation? That doesn't account for the full range of variation, though. Is it simply the case that noone has derived a set of assumptions for logistic regression?

Roback & Legler:


Nothing says the outcome in a logistic regression must be binary. Indeed, logistic regressions can estimate the probability parameters of binomial distributions just fine, even if a common use is with a binary outcome.

@Dave are you referring to item 1? Please reread it carefully. (I agree it is badly named.)

You need to specify assumptions for which properties of which estimator. Logistic regression is a model, not a method; it can be estimated in many ways and its estimates can have many properties. E.g., assumptions for consistency, assumptions for uniqueness, assumptions for valid inference using MLE SEs, etc. See this post for an example of different assumptions related to different properties of the OLS estimator of the linear regression model.

@Noah would you not say that linearity, independence, normality of residuals and homoskedasticity are properties of the linear regression model?  I've never seen the model described without those properties, although the last three are generally collapsed into $\epsilon_i \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$ i.i.d.

@Mohan not at all. Those are not properties of a model; they may be assumptions required for specific properties to hold of the OLS estimates, like unbiasedness, being BLUE, or exact inference using the standard variance, but none of those are required to specify, run, or interpret a linear regression model.

@Noah see “When we use a linear regression model, we are implicitly making some assumptions about the variables in Equation (5.1).” in https://otexts.com/fpp2/regression-intro.html

@Noah or “In Chapter 3, we will consider the normal linear regression model, which explicitly assumes that the error term u is normally distributed” in https://uk.sagepub.com/sites/default/files/upm-binaries/94356_Chapter_2_The_Classical_Linear_Regression_Model_%28CLRM%29.pdf

@Mohan Those chapters are simplifications, and the authors are omitting important context. No assumptions are required to use or posit a model or estimator, but assumptions are required for those estimators to achieve certain properties. See Berk et al. (2021) for an account of linear regression that is assumption-lean. You don't need homoscedasticity to run a linear regression or for OLS to be unbiased; you need it for the usual SEs to be valid. But who says we have to use the usual SEs?

@Noah I think we are arguing over terminology. Berk et al explicitly say that they have a reinterpretation that departs from conventional approaches: ‘Conventional approaches are laden with assumptions that are questionable, many of which are effectively untestable (Box, 1976, Leamer, 1878; Rubin, 1986;  Cox, 1995; Berk, 2003; Freedman, 2004; 2009). We discuss here some implications of an “assumption lean” reinterpretation of regression.’
